# Select only one checkbox HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with checking only one checkbox... I tried two types of JS code.. But it doesn't work... To check by class, when u click on one element with class 'product-list' to deselect another... Have someone idea how to solve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="mg-toolbar">
  <div class="mg-option checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
    <input class="product-list" type="checkbox" name="PDF" value="<?php echo $file_name; ?>">
    <label for="file_1">SELECT</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Try 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.product-list').click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
   );
</script>
```

JS Try 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.product-list').on('change', function() {
     $('.product-list').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you need a radio button instead.

Comment: I see only one checkbox in your HTML sample, so I think I do not understand what's the problem :/

Comment: @Raptor I tried and with radio button too

Comment: Agreed, if you only want one checkbox to be selected at once, then actually that's what radio buttons were invented for. And it doesn't need any JS code to make that work.

Comment: Radio button does not require JavaScript to work.

Comment: Did you name those radio buttons the same?

Comment: @DylanBarquilla its a HTML part of code.. It's dynamic, I made a list of files from directory in PHP

Comment: Your second example works correctly, unless you dynamically add /remove checkboxes

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Try `$('.product-list').on('change','.checkbox-custom', function() {
     $('.product-list').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
   });`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that only one item to be selected at once, then actually that's what radio buttons were invented for (rather than checkboxes). And you don't need any JS code to make that work.

Demo:

```html
<div class="mg-toolbar">
  <div class="mg-option checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
    <input class="product-list" id="file_1" type="radio" name="PDF" value="File1">
    <label for="file_1">SELECT 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mg-option checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
    <input class="product-list" id="file_2" type="radio" name="PDF" value="File2">
    <label for="file_2">SELECT 2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mg-option checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
    <input class="product-list" id="file_3" type="radio" name="PDF" value="File3">
    <label for="file_3">SELECT 3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mg-option checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
    <input class="product-list" id="file_4" type="radio" name="PDF" value="File4">
    <label for="file_4">SELECT 4</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That the right way to do. One thing tho is that label's "for" attribute should match id of the input, or label should wrap the input element

Comment: @Apolo quite right, I overlooked that. Corrected now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change the #c01 and #c02 to the two check box ID's your doing this with.
I think this may do what you need it to do. If c01 checked, c02 is unchecked, and vice-versa

```
 $("#c01").click(function(){
        if($("#c01").is(':checked'))
        $("#c02").prop("checked", false);
    });
    
    $("#c02").click(function(){
        if($("#c02").is(':checked'))
        $("#c01").prop("checked", false);
    });
```

Comment: Hm...this won't scale if there are more than 2 checkboxes (which, since the OP says it's a list of files loaded dynamically from a folder, there's a very good chance there might be). Anyway, far easier to just use radio buttons so that no extra code is required to manipulate them and ensure a single selection.